# Displaying list using JSTL in a Spring MVC Web Application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

.jsp

```
 <c:forEach items = "${allContacts}" var="contact">
            <c:out value="${contact.firstName}"/>,
            <c:out value="${contact.lastName}"/>
     </c:forEach>
```

ContactService.java

```
  public static List listContacts() {
        return toList(contacts);

    }

    private static List toList(Map contacts) {
        List contactList = new ArrayList();
        Iterator iterator = contacts.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
            Contact contact = (Contact) entry.getValue();
            contactList.add(contact);
        }
        return contactList;
    }
```

ListContactsController.java

```
public class ListContactsController extends AbstractController {

    public ListContactsController() {
    }

    public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        List allContacts = ContactService.listContacts();

        return new ModelAndView("ListContacts","allContacts", allContacts);
    }
}
```

I am trying to list `allContacts`, but is only shows "," as output. The data shows in GET but does not display in the webpage. What is the problem?

Comment: could you please post the Class of the object you put into the `allContacts` list.

Comment: I mean the objects in the list returned by ContactService.listContacts()!

Answer (score 2):

You might not have added your `allContacts` object in your controller:

```
session.setAttribute("allContacts", allContactsVariable);
```

@Ralph's comment:

Since a comma is printed out, it means that there are objects existing in your list but the objects do not have values in their fields.

Have you tried adding the values after your GET? E.g., `contact1.setFirstName("value");` OR `contact.setLastName("value")`

Comment: This can not be the problem, because if the collection allContracts is empty or null then there would be no `,` in the output!

Comment: you should not be using session with spring MVC unless it is needed. in spring MVC, you should add your object/variable to the model.

Comment: Where i want to do this change